# Is it possible to get multiple rows with maximum values without subquery or self join? -- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this `employee` table:

```
id|sal

1 |20000

2 |15000            1 |20000
            ===>  
3 |10000            5 |20000

4 |15000

5 |20000
```

I want to get multiple rows with maximum value with the requirement of **not using any sub-query or self join**. I did it like:

```
SELECT emp.id, emp.sal
FROM employee as emp
LEFT JOIN employee as emp1 ON emp1.id = emp1.id AND emp1.sal > emp.sal
WHERE emp1.id IS NULL
```

But this uses a self join. Is there any solution of it? Can this be done without sub-query or self join? Any suggestions will be helpful.

**EDIT:**

`select` in `select` is also restricted.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: `Server version: 8.0.18 - MySQL Community Server - GPL`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid these features?

Comment: Just a task. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

considering your comment and edit it seems you find dense_rank window function

```
with cte as(
select *, dense_rank() over(order by sal desc) as rn from employee
) select id,sal from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is also a good approach!

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper . . . This is the correct answer and should be accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SET @salary := -1;

SELECT id, salary
FROM
(
    SELECT *, if(@salary = salary, @rank, @rank := @rank +1) AS rank, @salary:= salary
    FROM employee
    ORDER BY salary DESC
) AS another_table
WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: I don't think it's without sub-query, you have `select` in `select` which is called subquery.

Comment: It is called temporary tables. :)

Comment: you may be right, but i need it without select in select. BTW thanks for answering

Comment: Then don't you think you should edit your question and try to be more specific? I ain't being rude but please try to be specific from next time onwards.

Comment: Yeah man thanks. I was not having knowledge of temporary tables. I feel bad for you that you have written answer with effort and should be accepted which wasn't. So I am accepting your answer. Thanks for introducing the concept of temporary tables :)

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper, no problem. Glad this answer helped.

Comment: @UsmanDeveloper . . . This answer should not be accepted.  It is assigning variables and then using the values in two separate expressions -- MySQL *explicitly* warns against doing this in the document.  Further, the use of variables for this purpose has been deprecated.  You should accept and use Zaynul's approach.